# Desktop, mobile and AMP versions of website

Tags: seo, canonical-link, amp-html

I have a web site www.example.com and the relative mobile version in m.example.com and now I have the AMP version in amp.example.com.

From www.example.com I have redirect to m.example.it for mobile device and I use for AMP page:

```
<link rel="amphtml" …
```

From m.example.com I have only canonical tag to desktop version.

From amp.example.com I have only canonical tag to desktop version.

It's ok?
I need to link AMP version from m.example.com too?

After 3 weeks Google Search Console found the AMP page, the AMP page are in Google cache, but I don't ever see my AMP page in search result (I'm in Google News) and I don't count traffic.

Do you think is all configured correctly?

Answer (score 2):

actually it doesn't say "**any** non-AMP page" but "we add information about the AMP page to the non-AMP page and vice versa"

furthermore John Mueller explained it a little more here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/fFQJC2m0OHs

```
https://www.example.com/desktop/page.html (this is the desktop version of the page) has:
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"  href="https://m.example.com/mobile/page.html">
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://a.example.com/amp/page.html">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/desktop/page.html">

https://m.example.com/mobile/page.html (this is the smartphone version of the page) has:
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/desktop/page.html">

https://a.example.com/amp/page.html (this is the AMP version of the page) has:
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/desktop/page.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `<link rel="amphtml" href="#amp page url#">` on *both* the mobile and desktop pages ("On **any** non-AMP page, reference the AMP version of the page" - source).

Unrelated to AMP but [necessary for proper indexing of separate mobile content in Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls), from desktop pages you'll need `<link rel="alternate" href="m.example.com/mobile-version/">` – so there's a bi-directional `rel="canonical"` and `rel="alternate"` between mobile and desktop versions of content.

You should also serve a `Vary: User-Agent` HTTP header (although there are reports of this causing issues with CDNs, which you should look into if applicable).